# Android Java SQLite not updating?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am going nuts over here. I have been trying to update one column in one row inside of my SQLite Database but its just not happening regardless of what I try.The value is never updated and there are no exceptions in my log.

The below code might summarise my problem best.
the `updateLatestMessage()` function is part of a Database Controller Class.

```
  public void updateLatestMessage(int messageID, int chatID){
    Log.d("DB", "message ID =" + messageID); //example output = 125
    Log.d("DB", "chat ID =" + chatID); //example output = 2

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("latest_message_id", messageID);
        db.update("chat", cv, "chat_id = ?" + chatID, null);
        db.close();
        //db.update(tableChat.TABLE_NAME, cv, tableChat.getChatId() + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(chatID)}); // tried this before didn't work either


    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("DB", "Error: "+e.toString());
    }

}
```

currently latest message has the ID of 5

```
        myDB.chat.updateLatestMessage((int) messageID, globalChatID);//calling the above DB update code
```

after running this code the latest message still has the id of 5 instead of 125

I am expecting the messageID to be updated inside of the the latest_message_id column inside my already existing chat row.

Comment: It's suggested to use the Room API when working with SQL in android, one of the advantages to Room is that it won't compile if there is an error in the SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the table is `"chat"`, the name of the column in the `WHERE` clause is `"chat_id"` and the argument of `WHERE` clause is `chatID`, then the recommended way for the update is this:

```
int result = db.update("chat", cv, "chat_id = ?", new String[]{String.ValueOf(chatID)});
```

Check the value of `result` after the statement.
If its value is greater than 0 then the update was successful.

Comment: I replaced the line with yours, still no effect even though it is returning a 1. Might I add that the message ID inside the sqlight table is set to be an Integer, might that be the cause of it ?

Comment: If the return value of update() is 1 then the row has been updated. If you don't see the updated value then the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: the odd thing is that i am reading the LatestMessageID prior to running the update code and immediately after. and in both cases the value remains the same even though the new Message id is passed into the update function and apparently given the 1, stored correctly. there is just no other code in this scenario. Any Ideas?

Comment: updateLatestMessage() is a method that updates a row of your table. I can't tell if you use it to update the row with the latest message id. But what is certain is that if the update() method returns a positive value then one or more rows were updated.

Comment: if let's assume the message_id column is set to be an Integer would I have to change the layout of the update function in anyways.